# Restore IAP in Android using Prime 31

Tags: unity, android, google-play, plugin, in-app-purchase

can someone please guide me how to restore purchases in android using prime 31.

What my basic understating is to get the list skus which player has purchased after he logs in with his account and restore them accordingly.

What I am not getting is how to get that list.